# HttpModules and race conditions

Tags: asp.net

Here is the complete source code for an HttpModule I'm working on. 
As you can see, I record the time during the **BeginRequest** event, store it in a private field,  and calculate the elapsed time during the **EndRequest** event.

Can I safely assume that the _RequestStart field won't be overwritten by another request before the EndRequest event fires? Does asp.net use the same instance of this HttpModule to service multiple simultaneous requests?

```
   public class TimingModule : IHttpModule 
   {
       private DateTime _RequestStart;

       public void Dispose() {}

       public void Init(HttpApplication context)
       {
           context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
           context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(OnEndRequest);
       }

       private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;

           if (app.Context.Response.BufferOutput)
           {

               TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_RequestStart);
               app.Context.Response.AddHeader("X-ServerTiming",ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
           }
       }

       private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           _RequestStart = DateTime.Now;
       }
   }
```

Comment: That's fairly easy to verify! If I remember correctly, the very same instance is used so thus your code would not work correctly. Rather, use the `Items` container from the context to store and retrieve the information you'd like to pass from start to end.

Comment: How would you verify it? The code works fine in my dev environment, I'm just concerned it will give inaccurate results under load.

Comment: Have `Thread.Sleep` somewhere in the pipeline and issue two concurrent requests.

Comment: Not an answer but the following post shows both approaches; the approach shown in the OP and the one suggested by @WiktorZychla http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/121_Display_Request_Processing_Time_in_ASPNet_pages.aspx

Comment: I created a page that sleeps for 20 seconds and issued other requests. The results suggest that the code above works. The long running page always returns a result over 20,000ms. However that could be because the other requests happened to be serviced by another thread. However I'd like to know this would always be the case.